# NHibernate QueryOver with nested select in FROM

Tags: nhibernate, criteria-api, queryover

How would you write the following using QueryOver (or CriteriaAPI for that matter)?

```
select foo from (select 1 as foo) as bar
```

Comment: AIFAIK Criteria and Queryover (a wrapper around Criteria) cant have queries in the from clause. you have to resort to smth like `select (select 1 as foo) from bar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not totally obvious if you use the `QueryOver` interface - which is more complex and subtle than it first appears. Consider using `NHibernate.Linq.LinqExtensionMethods.Query<T>`:

```
session.Query<Person>().Select(p => p.Husband).Select(p => p.Name).ToList()
```

Will give you a `List<string>`, corresponding to the sql:

```
select h.name from (select husband as h from person) as h
```

Comment: The actual query was more complex than that, which was later re-written to avoid such nested selects (probably for the better anyway). I haven't used LinqExtensionMethods yet, looks quite interesting though, and certainly seems like it has the required functionality.

Comment: It's meant to be a bit closer to Linq than standard QueryOvers. I've had trouble doing custom fetching with them, or anything much more complex, e.g. `session.Query<Person>().Where(p => p.Husband.Name == "Clive")` won't work (whereas `session.QueryOver<Person>().Fetch(p => p.Husband).Eager.WhereRestrictonOn... and so on` will do just what you'd expect.

Comment: So far I've had no trouble implementing queries with QueryOver apart from mentioned above, but I've simplified the query since. I have not seen a possibility to do a join on multiple fields, however.

Comment: What sort of Join? You can do, for example:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066381/nhibernate-self-join-on-multiple-fields